# Overlaying an yuv Image over another image

Tags: c, image-processing

I want to overlay an yuv image over another yuv image . Suppose if there is 640x 480 image , i want to overlay a small size image at the right bottom of the source image .
please help.

Comment: There are many variations of YUV images, planar and biplanar ones, full or reduced color information (such as 422 or 420). Can you somewhat more specific about the format at hand?

Comment: hi Codo ...  Can u please give some idea for yuv 420 planer for now

Comment: Are you going to re-ask this question for every image format?

Comment: no .. but how it will be diff for interleave format

Answer (score 3):

A planar YUV 420 image consists of 640 x 480 bytes of Y sample, followed by 320 x 240 bytes of U samples and 320 x 240 bytes of V samples. Since there only exists color information for each 2x2 block (and not for every pixel), I'll assume that all image sizes ond positions are a multiple of 2. (Otherwise it gets far more complicated.)

Furthermore, I'll assume that there is not padding at the end of a row, between the Y and U or between the U and V samples.

```
void copyRect(unsigned char* targetImage, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, 
    unsigned char* sourceImage, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight,
    int sourceLeft, int sourceTop,
    int width, int height,
    int targetLeft, int targetTop)
{
    // Y samples
    unsigned char* tgt = targetImage + targetTop * targetWidth + targetLeft;
    unsigned char* src = sourceImage + sourceTop * sourceWidth + sourceLeft;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        memcpy(tgt, src, width);
        tgt += targetWidth;
        src += sourceWidth;
    }

    // U samples
    tgt = targetImage + targetHeight * targetWidth
        + (targetTop / 2) * (targetWidth / 2) + (targetLeft / 2);
    src = sourceImage + sourceHeight * sourceWidth
        + (sourceTop / 2) * (sourceWidth / 2) + (sourceLeft / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; i++) {
        memcpy(tgt, src, width / 2);
        tgt += targetWidth / 2;
        src += sourceWidth / 2;
    }

    // V samples
    tgt = targetImage + targetHeight * targetWidth + (targetHeight / 2) * (targetWidth / 2)
        + (targetTop / 2) * (targetWidth / 2) + (targetLeft / 2);
    src = sourceImage + sourceHeight * sourceWidth + (sourceHeight / 2) * (sourceWidth / 2)
        + (sourceTop / 2) * (sourceWidth / 2) + (sourceLeft / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; i++) {
        memcpy(tgt, src, width / 2);
        tgt += targetWidth / 2;
        src += sourceWidth / 2;
    }
}
```

I've never tried to compile the code. So no guarantees.

The parameters are:

*targetImage*: pixel data of target image, where the other image is copied to

*targetWidth*, *targetHeigt*: dimension of target image

*sourceImage*: pixel data of source image, part of which is copied into the other image

sourceWidth, *sourceHeight*: dimension of source image

*sourceLeft*, *sourceTop*: top left position within source image of area to be copied

*width*, *height*: size of area to be copied

*targetLeft*, *targetTop*: top left position within target image, where the area is copied to

Comment: Codo, how is it you never tried to compile this code? You mean you just sat down and written it from the head? :)

Comment: Yes. I've just detected and correct to minor bugs and added a description of the parameters.